# Tomcat 9 : Shutdown if one container failed to start

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

I use a Tomcat 9 instance to deploy multiple webapps.
These webapps are declared in "conf/server.xml" like this (because I need to control path) :

```xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false">
    <Context docBase="webapp1_1.0" path="/webapp1" override="true"/>
    <Context docBase="webapp2_1.0" path="/webapp2" override="true"/>
    ...
</Host>
```

My problem is that if one webapp failed to start, a shutdown is forced and Tomcat stop

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start SEVERE: [Thread-0] The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
```

Is it possible to start Tomcat anyway with the started webapps ?

Thanks